# Create ids with conditions R

Tags: r

I would like to create an id grouping two columns, and taking into account the duplicates. To make it more clear here below an example from my dataset:

```r
data<-data.frame(event =c("1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3"), code = c("64 2 16 204", "64 204", "70 2 05 002", "70 002", "60 1 15 001","64 2 16 204", "60 1 15 076"))
```

In the data above, "64 2 16 204" appears twice in two different events - ie., event 1 and 3. Hence I would like all the codes in event 1 and 3 to have the same id.

The output wanted is then:

```r
data<-data.frame(event=c("1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3"), code = c("64 2 16 204", "64 204", "70 2 05 002", "70 002", "60 1 15 001","64 2 16 204", "60 1 15 076"), group_id =c("1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1"))
```

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Your output seems not complete.

Comment: Yes sorry I edited the output

Comment: Are you looking for base R solutions?

Comment: Yes please (if its possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something raw:

```
tmp = aggregate(event ~ code, data = data, \(x) sort(unique(x)))
tmp = tmp[lengths(tmp$event) > 1, "event"]

data$group_id = data$event
for (i in seq_along(tmp)) {
  for (ev in tmp[[i]][-1]) {
    data[data$event == ev, "group_id"] = tmp[[i]][1]
  }
}  

#   event        code group_id
# 1     1 64 2 16 204        1
# 2     1      64 204        1
# 3     2 70 2 05 002        2
# 4     2      70 002        2
# 5     3 60 1 15 001        1
# 6     3 64 2 16 204        1
# 7     3 60 1 15 076        1
```